# Read formatted text in Java

Tags: java, file, format

I'm trying to read a formatted file in Java, I used to do this pretty well in C but no clue here. The example line is:

A '0' B C

And I want to take A and 0 as two separated Strings and [B, C] as two Strings in a String ArrayList.

The line fomrat can be modified in anyway, for example adding commas

A '0' B, C, D...

Any idea on how to split this? I used to do it with fseek, fread, etc when working in C

Comment: Please add your code so you can receive help.

Comment: There's no code, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Plese try the below code: Idea here is to use the Java "Scanner" class.
This will read the file by line until end of file is reached.

```
import java.io.File;  
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class fileReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      File oFile = new File("myfile.txt");
      Scanner oScanner= new Scanner(oFile );
      while (oScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String sLine = oScanner.nextLine(); //Next line will point to the next line on the file
        System.out.println(sLine ); //And any other operations on the line you would like to perform.
      }
      oScanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Error Occurred");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do let me know in case of any more questions

Comment: Almost 3 years have passed, I'm sorry I haven't answered before, I ended up figuring it out myself, even though your answer was so soon it was my first time using stackoverflow and probably I didn't even get a notification, I've just signed in again now hahaha. Thanks for your answer though, I appreciate it, sorry for not answering before.